# C++: I can't start my class, I get class was not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++

I'm using netbeans with gcc compiler and when I try to declare an object of my class, and run the code I get the class was not delclared in this scope error, this is my code in main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Clock r;
    r.processH();

    return 0;
}

class Clock {

private:
    int h, m, s;
    char conv[];

    Clock() {
        h = 0;
        m = 0;
        s = 0;
        conv[10] = {};
    }

public:

    void processH() {
        int r =0; 
        while(r <= 2){
            conv[r] = 'I';
            if(conv == "III") {
                conv[0] = 'V';
                conv[1] = 'I';
                r++;
                break;
            }
            r++;
        }
        cout<< r;
    }

};
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not an experienced OOP programmer.

Comment: Your file should have main() function written after the class Clock declaration.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should declare the class before you use it's name. In your case it should be above the `main` function.

Second, you declared `Reloj` function with no return type, which is illegal.

The correct code may look like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Clock {
private:
    int h, m, s;
    char conv[];

    void Reloj() {
        h = 0;
        m = 0;
        s = 0;
        conv[10] = {};
    }

public:

    void processH(int ent) {
        int r =0; 
        while(r <= 2) {
            conv[r] = 'I';
            if(conv == "III") {
                conv[0] = 'V';
                conv[1] = 'I';
                r++;
                break;
            }
            r++;
        }
        cout<< r;
    }
};


int main() {
    Clock r;
    r.processH(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a complement to Sergey's answer : You could also forward declare the class.
Just add the line

```
class Clock;
```

before your `main` function to tell the compiler that the class exists.